# How to use a mutable Param pyomo?

Tags: pyomo

I'm trying to make Param mutable with initializer zero but when I tried to read the Param in the constraint its doesn't understand what is reading, the only way that I found to read is using .value but when the problem finishes declaring the whole constraint. the solver found the first solution but when I defined the new param value, it doesn't change the value of the param. I know if I am doing bad the declared or I haven't found the correct white to do that.

As a solver im using CPLEX

This is the way i defined the Param:

```
model.s_value = pe.Param(mutable=True, initialize=0)
```

But if I use the Param as a normal Param is a constraint promo sent this message:

```
   ValueError: Constraint 'def_constraint[0]' encountered a strict inequality expression ('>' or '<'). All constraints must be formulated using using '<=', '>=', or '=='.
```

I think is because when pyomo tired to read the param that sends an object like this:

```
pyomo.core.base.param.IndexedParam object at 0x1939C6A0
```

After declaring all the variable I put the solver inside a for and there I redefine the value of the Param:

```
model.s_value.value= new_value
```

Please. Someone can explain to me who can I use correctly the mutable Param and how can I iterate the model.

Comment: It seems like the error is more about the type of inequality instead. There are very few cases when a strict inequality is needed, and most of the time, your solver won't allow it anyway. So, have you tried reformulating your constraints with `<=` or `>=` inequalities?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example of changing the value of a mutable parameter.  You didn't post a full set of executable code above, so it is difficult to figure out what is going on.  If this below doesn't answer your question, request you update (edit) your post above with a minimal reproducible example.

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

m = pyo.ConcreteModel()

m.x = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
m.p = pyo.Param(mutable=True, initialize = 10)

# the problem
m.OBJ = pyo.Objective(expr=m.x)
m.c1 = pyo.Constraint(expr=m.x >= m.p)

solver = pyo.SolverFactory('glpk')

# solve it...  
results = solver.solve(m)
m.display()    # x=10

# change the mutable parameter
m.p = 5

# re-solve it
results = solver.solve(m)
m.display()    # x=5
```